# Aggregating data in optional arrays in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Using the MongoDB aggregation pipeline, is there a way to sum a value in an optional array field?

Suppose this collection:

```
db.myCollection.insert([
   {_id: 1}, 
   { _id: 2,
     events: [{_id: 201, value: 10}, {_id:202, value:20}]
   }])
```

I would like to sum the events.value field using the aggregation pipeline, to produce this:

```
{_id: 1, totalValue: 0},
{_id: 2, totalValue: 30}
```

I can't use `{$unwind: "$events"}` because that would eliminate `{_id: 1}` from the output, so I tried to push the values to an array, and use `$cond` to create a single `[0]` if the element is missing:

```
 db.myCollection.aggregate([
   {$group: {_id:"$_id", values: {$push: "$events.value"}}},
   {$project: {_id:1, values: {$cond: {
     if: {$gt: [{$size: "$values"}, 0]},
     then: "$values",
     else: [[0]]
     }}}}  ])
```

This creates the following output:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "values" : [ [ 10, 20 ] ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "values" : [ [ 0 ] ] }
```

Now I can use `$unwind` on the values, but I am unable to sum the values.

Using `$group` with `$sum`

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
   {$group: {_id:"$_id", values: {$push: "$events.value"}}},
   {$project: {_id:1, values: {$cond: {
     if: {$gt: [{$size: "$values"}, 0]},
     then: "$values",
     else: [[0]]
     }}}},
   {$unwind: "$values"},
   {$group: {_id:"$_id", totalValue: {$sum: "$values"}}}  ])
```

produces this:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "totalValue" : 0 }
{ "_id" : 2, "totalValue" : 0 }
```

and using `$project` with `$add` produces an error:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
   {$group: {_id:"$_id", values: {$push: "$events.value"}}},
   {$project: {_id:1, values: {$cond: {
     if: {$gt: [{$size: "$values"}, 0]},
     then: "$values",
     else: [[0]]
     }}}},
   {$project: {_id:1, totalValue: {$add: "$values"}}}  ])
```

results in an exception:

```
 exception: $add only supports numeric or date types, not Array
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your documents may or may not contain an array element for what you wish to sum. So before doing any [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) operation you apply the [**`$ifNull`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) operator with [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/). This takes the field to test as an argument, and an alternate value which is returned if the field is not present or evaluates to `null`, otherwise the value of the field that exists is returned:

```js
db.myCollection.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
        "events": { "$ifNull": [ "$events", [{ "value": 0 }] ] }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$events" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "totalValue": { "$sum": "$events.value" }
    }}
])
```

A much simplified form since content is neither removed due to missing an array and is replaced with a default value that works you your intention.

Answer (score 0):

I was missing an `$unwind` statement:

After one `$unwind`:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
{$group: {_id:"$_id", values: {$push: "$events.value"}}},
{$project: {_id:1, values: {$cond: {
  if: {$gt: [{$size: "$values"}, 0]},
  then: "$values",
  else: [[0]]
  }}}},
{$unwind: "$values"} ])
```

I get this:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "values" : [ 10, 20 ] }
{ "_id" : 1, "values" : [ 0 ] }
```

But if I add a second `$unwind`:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
{$group: {_id:"$_id", values: {$push: "$events.value"}}},
{$project: {_id:1, values: {$cond: {
  if: {$gt: [{$size: "$values"}, 0]},
  then: "$values",
  else: [[0]]
  }}}},
{$unwind: "$values"},
{$unwind: "$values"}])
```

I get this:

```
{ "_id" : 2, "values" : 10 }
{ "_id" : 2, "values" : 20 }
{ "_id" : 1, "values" : 0 }
```

Now I can add the `$group` clause:

```
db.myCollection.aggregate([
{$group: {_id:"$_id", values: {$push: "$events.value"}}},
{$project: {_id:1, values: {$cond: {
  if: {$gt: [{$size: "$values"}, 0]},
  then: "$values",
  else: [[0]]
  }}}},
{$unwind: "$values"},
{$unwind: "$values"},
{$group: {_id:"$_id", totalValue: {$sum: "$values"}}}])
```

producing the desired result:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "totalValue" : 0 }
{ "_id" : 2, "totalValue" : 30 }
```

Comment: Got this working, but the answer feels too complex. Any simpler solutions out there?

Comment: Store the sum on the document and update it when you update the array.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately not an option here, as I querying data created by a third-party application.